# System time set notification

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible for an app to detect when the devices time/date has been set by the user/auto updated?

I'm thinking, something like Reachability for the system clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is the [`UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) notification which is trigged by changes.

> Posted when there is a significant change in time, for example, change
>   to a new day (midnight), carrier time update, and change to or from
>   daylight savings time. This notification does not contain a userInfo
>   dictionary.

You just add an observer to the `NSNotificationCenter` for that notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleTimeChangeWithNotification:) name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the [`applicationSignificantTimeChange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationSignificantTimeChange%3a) method in your appDelegate and/or you can subscribe to the [`UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification) event.

From the Apple documentation -

> Examples of significant time changes include the arrival of midnight, an update of the time by a carrier, and the change to daylight savings time. The delegate can implement this method to adjust any object of the app that displays time or is sensitive to time changes.