# C# Xamarin IOS: Equivalent of SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() in C# IOS Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I need to keep the time since the application has started. The time needs to be keep ticking even though the device went to sleep mode.

In Android there is `SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime()` which keeps ticking on sleep.

In IOS there is `NSProcessInfo.processInfo().systemUptime` but this will stop ticking when the device went to sleep mode.

I saw many implementations using some kernel timer but they are all written on Objective-C or Swift. I need to use the Xamarin cross platform library, which I do not know how to convert those code into C#.

Answer (score 1):

Is it an option to store the current time when the app starts. And when you need to know the time interval, subtract the stored time from the current time?

This will work if no event logic is required during sleep.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will use database to store the value, but is there a time variable I can use which does not get affected if the user change their date and time of their device?

Comment: To minimize problems with daylight saving time in some countries you could use and store the UTC time (this will prevent a potential error twice a year). If you want to handle the event when time changes, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756825/system-time-set-notification. This link's example is in objective-c but these classes should be accessible in Xamarin. With this sample you can react in the event the time changes (daylight saving, user, midnight, etc...)

Comment: If the user change the device time manually will the UTC time get changed too? For example if the user change their timezone which will affect the time offset.

Comment: Yes, it does. The time functions are conversions from and to the requested format or UTC (many devices use an internal clock that runs in UTC time, but reports it differently to the user depending on the device settings).